# Programmatically add binding to ItemsSource of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display different tables in a DataGrid. I don't want to create a DataGrid for each table. So I have to dynamically add the ItemsSource of the DataGrid from the code.
How can I achieve this (WPF) `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in the C# code.

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track. So what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know what the code is to add the binding from the C# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the databinding to the property on your ViewModel that you want to bind to...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTable}"/>
</Window>
```

Set the datacontext (I prefer to do it in Xaml, but that's more than I like to do for an example)...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Create the property on you ViewModel...

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataTable currentTable;

    public DataTable CurrentTable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currentTable;
        }
        set
        {
            this.currentTable = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentTable"));
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Column1");
        table.Columns.Add("Column2");
        table.Rows.Add("This is column1", "this is column2");

        CurrentTable = table;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

All you have to do now is set the CurrentTable property to whatever table you want and it will update the UI and display it.